# Google cloud - file pipe

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a system that is able to produce a custom video (based on input text) faster than real-time.

I would like to create an HTTP endpoint: `/create_video?description=dog riding a horse` that, as part of the response, returns the URL to the produced video.

Video can be quite long, and its generation can take some time. Rather than waiting for it to complete, I would like to return the response as soon as first frames are available, such that the user can watch instantly using the provided URL (we generate faster than real-time, so there will be no buffering). The URL must point to generate video indefinitely (even months after generation).

I am using Google Cloud. What would be the recommended way to do that?

I could create a custom endpoint that serves the videos, and has the described properties, but maybe something as simple as Cloud Storage could work (I was not able to get it to read while writing was not finalized though)?

Comment: An object in Cloud Storage is not accessible until the write process is complete. Until then the object does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, after doing some extra research it seems to not be that easy. My best idea is to implement a custom endpoint that streams the result, while the file is being generated using temporary array entry in DB. Once the file is fully generated (db entry will be empty and point to cloud storage location), redirects to cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Piotr Dabkowski, after doing some extra research it seems to not be that easy. My best idea is to implement a custom endpoint that streams the result, while the file is being generated using temporary array entry in DB. Once the file is fully generated (db entry will be empty and point to cloud storage location), redirects to cloud storage.